# Matching ID from within subquery MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Feel free to point out if I'm doing this completely wrong, however I do feel I'm getting close.

I have two tables, tracks and artist, structured like this:

[image: table structure]

I already wrote a query which gets the *most common genre* of an artist **with a given artID** based on the number of tracks that artist has for each genre:

```
SELECT `trackGenre` AS commonGenre
  FROM `tracks`
  WHERE artID=$artID
  GROUP BY `trackGenre`
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

However now what I'm trying to do is select * from artists where the artName matches a search query AND the most common genre from an artist = a specific genre. Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM artist
  WHERE artName LIKE '%example%'
    AND (SELECT trackGenre AS commonGenre
      FROM `tracks`
      WHERE ????
      GROUP BY `trackGenre`
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
      LIMIT 1)='Rock'
```

I really appreciate any tips, can't quite wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple, used:
`artist.artID=tracks.artID`
in the WHERE clause of the query. Thanks!